# List all repository branches in Jenkins Parameter

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, git-remote

I am trying to add Active choice paramtere for Jenkins job to populate all the github branches. I've added personal access token in Jenkins credentials and trying to use that.
so, far I've tried below snippets.

```
def gettags = ("git ls-remote https://<username>@github.com/<username>/first-project.git").execute()
return gettags.text.readLines().collect { 
 it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '')
}
```

but, it's not working, so I try to execute in jenkins script and it keeps running, and when I try to run just first line, it gives me `Result: Process[pid=17092, exitValue="not exited"]`, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the GitHub API instead?

```
def accessToken = "ACCESS_TOKEN".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
def get = new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/branches").openConnection();
get.setRequestProperty("authorization", "Basic " + accessToken)

def content = get.getInputStream().getText()

def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(content)
return object["name"]
```

Comment: I'm using the personal token stored in Jenkins credentials, dont want to pass the token in jenkins job.

Comment: @SumitMonapara you don't need to hardcode the credentials. You get the credentials from the store and use it here. This is the best approach IMV.

Answer (score 0):

**I got the answer**, Actually, as the user name, I was using the user ID that I set as the Jenkins credentials instead of the **actual GitHub username**, so I replaced that username and the groovy script is working fine.

Thank you.